# redux-form: How to update FormSection name prop

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-form

I'm trying to update `FormSection` name prop after I press my `New Post` button because the prop `name` of my `FormSection` holds the `postUid`, and when I press the button I generate a new uid, hence a new post.

Is there a **nice** way to do this?

The problem is that **even if I destroy the form state, and even if I re-register the fields, the loaded component will still use the old state**.

That's the real issue here, I don't want to refresh the page, ou unmount and mount the component.
Any help? Thanks <3

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to re-initialize the form. There is a setting `enableReinitialize` in [documantation](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/)

Example:

```
const ReduxedMyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'MyForm',
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(MyForm);
```

Comment: I could not get your suggestion to work, see this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/0Rw1mMrNG
Any different suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can assign/override form name using `form` attribute, when using your Form component.

for example:

```
import NewPostForm from '../forms/NewPostForm';



<NewPostForm form={`dynamicName_${formId}`}    
    initialValues={{... ... }} />
```